# Using path options to set color for a custom shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, shading

I'm using a custom shading to make cylindrical bars.

The shading uses a color that is defined in the color list.

I can change the color by using a `\colorlet` expression.  But I'd like to be able to do it with an option in the draw command.

Here's my code, with my latest attempts to set the color commented out.  I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation or on stackexchange that shows me how to do it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\pgfdeclareradialshading[mycolor,white]
  {barendshading}
  {\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
  {color(0bp)=(white);
   color(28bp)=(mycolor);
   color(60bp)=(mycolor)}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading[mycolor,white]
  {barshading}
  {100bp}
  {color(0bp)=(mycolor); 
   color(25bp)=(mycolor); 
   color(55bp)=(white); 
   color(75bp)=(mycolor);
   color(100bp)=(mycolor)}

\def\cylindricalsphere{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
    \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarspheres}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsphere}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{}
  \state{final}{\cylindricalsphere}}

\def\cylindricalsegment{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
      {\pgfpoint{-.55pt}{-5pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{.55pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarsegments}{initial}
    {
      \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{
        %\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/path color}{pcolor}
        %\colorlet{mycolor}{pcolor}
        \cylindricalsegment}
      \state{middle}[width=1pt]{
        \cylindricalsegment}
      \state{final}{}
    } 

\tikzset{
    cylindricalbar/.style={
        preaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarspheres},
        postaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarsegments},
    }}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}


  \colorlet{mycolor}{blue}
  \path [cylindricalbar,color=green] (0,0) arc (90:0:3.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue shaded bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a new `TikZ option` to store the color and use it into shading declarations.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\tikzset{
    /tikz/cylindrical shading color/.store in=\mycolor,
    /tikz/cylindrical shading color=black
}

\pgfdeclareradialshading[\mycolor]
  {barendshading}
  {\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
  {color(0bp)=(white);
   color(28bp)=(\mycolor);
   color(60bp)=(\mycolor)}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading[\mycolor]
  {barshading}
  {100bp}
  {color(0bp)=(\mycolor); 
   color(25bp)=(\mycolor); 
   color(55bp)=(white); 
   color(75bp)=(\mycolor);
   color(100bp)=(\mycolor)}

\def\cylindricalsphere{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
    \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarspheres}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsphere}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{}
  \state{final}{\cylindricalsphere}}

\def\cylindricalsegment{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
      {\pgfpoint{-.55pt}{-5pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{.55pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarsegments}{initial}
    {
      \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{
        %\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/path color}{pcolor}
        %\colorlet{mycolor}{pcolor}
        \cylindricalsegment}
      \state{middle}[width=1pt]{
        \cylindricalsegment}
      \state{final}{}
    } 

\tikzset{
    cylindricalbar/.style={
        preaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarspheres},
        postaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarsegments},
    }}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical shading color=red] (0,0) arc (90:0:3.5);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical shading color=green] (0,-0.5) arc (90:0:2.75);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical shading color=blue] (0,-1) arc (90:0:2);
  \path [cylindricalbar] (0,-1.5) arc (90:0:1.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess your bar endings disappeared in some cases, too?

Comment: @cfr Do you have an example of disappearance?

Comment: @cfr. Yes. But I've not investigated the problem.

Comment: @PaulGaborit: In my code, change green bar to be: `\path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical shading color=green] (0,-0.5) arc (90:0:3.0);` and lower end disappears.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I tried the same with `-0.5`, but also had some where `y` was positive. I think if you change all the arcs to `90:0` in my answer, you'll get 2 disappearing lower ends, which is why I used `90:-5`.

Comment: @cfr The `final` state of `cylindricalbarspheres` decoration is always executed... but, sometimes, with bad angle and position! Very strange...

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use a `.code` handler and just set the colour directly.

```
  cylindrical bar colour/.code={
    \colorlet{mycolor}{#1}%
  },
  cylindrical bar colour=black,
```

This creates a key `cylindrical bar colour` whose argument will be used to set `mycolor`. `black` is used as an initial value.

Then,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [cylindricalbar] (0,.5)  arc (90:-5:4);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical bar colour=green] (0,0) arc (90:-5:3.5);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical bar colour=blue] (0,1) arc (90:-5:4.5);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical bar colour=magenta] (0,1.5) arc (90:-5:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives

[image: multi-coloured cylindrical bars]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations,shadings}
\pgfdeclareradialshading[mycolor,white]
{barendshading}
{\pgfpoint{0bp}{5bp}}
{color(0bp)=(white);
  color(28bp)=(mycolor);
  color(60bp)=(mycolor)}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[mycolor,white]
{barshading}
{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(mycolor);
  color(25bp)=(mycolor);
  color(55bp)=(white);
  color(75bp)=(mycolor);
  color(100bp)=(mycolor)}
\def\cylindricalsphere{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{5pt}
    \pgfshadepath{barendshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarspheres}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{\cylindricalsphere}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{}
  \state{final}{\cylindricalsphere}}
\def\cylindricalsegment{
  \begin{pgfscope}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
    {\pgfpoint{-.55pt}{-5pt}}
    {\pgfpoint{.55pt}{5pt}}
    \pgfshadepath{barshading}{\pgfdecoratedangle}
  \end{pgfscope}}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{cylindricalbarsegments}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=1pt,next state=middle]{
    %\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/path color}{pcolor}
    %\colorlet{mycolor}{pcolor}
    \cylindricalsegment}
  \state{middle}[width=1pt]{
    \cylindricalsegment}
  \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{
  cylindricalbar/.style={
    preaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarspheres},
    postaction={decorate,decoration=cylindricalbarsegments},
  },
  cylindrical bar colour/.code={
    \colorlet{mycolor}{#1}%
  },
  cylindrical bar colour=black,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [cylindricalbar] (0,.5)  arc (90:-5:4);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical bar colour=green] (0,0) arc (90:-5:3.5);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical bar colour=blue] (0,1) arc (90:-5:4.5);
  \path [cylindricalbar, cylindrical bar colour=magenta] (0,1.5) arc (90:-5:5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By the way, are your cylinder endings meant to disappear in some cases? I had to do some experimentation to get 4 arcs which all had two round ends.