# Two-color custom arrowhead tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm creating a custom arrowhead that needs to have two colors in its drawing.

One color is given as the standard option `color=`.

I have hardcoded the second color in the attached code.  I'd like to create an option (say `second color`) for the second color, but I don't know how to properly do that when defining an arrow head.  All of the examples in section 100 of the manual relate to dimensions, rather than colors.

To clarify, I'd like to have an option that would allow me to set the green interior to any other color I desired.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = twocolor,
  parameters = {%
   \the\pgfarrowlength 
  },
  setup code = {%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
    \pgfsetcolor{green}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.65\pgfarrowlength}{.4\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.4\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.65\pgfarrowlength}{-.4\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults = {%
   length = 2cm 
  },
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [color=red,arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm,color=blue]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: two-color standard arrowhead]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cfr The arrow head I showed was just an example.

Suppose I used this two-color arrow head instead:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    /pgf/arrow keys/second color/.store in=\mycolor,
    /pgf/arrow keys/second color=green
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = twocolor,
  parameters = {%
   \the\pgfarrowlength 
  },
  setup code = {%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
    \pgfsetcolor{\mycolor}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults = {%
   length = 2cm 
  },
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [color=red,arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm,color=blue,second color=orange]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now the stroke/fill option doesn't have the correct semantics.

[image: arrow head with two color split]

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on the answer to an earlier question of mine [Using path options to set color for a custom shading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354872/using-path-options-to-set-color-for-a-custom-shading/), I have been able to set pgfkeys that make this work.  However, I'm afraid that I'm working around the arrow caching mechanism by doing it, so I think it may not be optimal.

At any rate, here's the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    /pgf/arrow keys/second color/.store in=\mycolor,
    /pgf/arrow keys/second color=green
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = twocolor,
  parameters = {%
   \the\pgfarrowlength 
  },
  setup code = {%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
    \pgfsetcolor{\mycolor}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.65\pgfarrowlength}{.4\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.4\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.65\pgfarrowlength}{-.4\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults = {%
   length = 2cm 
  },
}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [color=red,arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm,color=blue,second color=orange]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd welcome any suggestions for better ways to do this.

[image: two-color arrow with orange center]

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work for me if I alter the inner colour without changing the main colour or the length. For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [color=red,arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm,color=blue,second color=orange]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
  \draw [color=red,arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm,color=blue,second color=green]}] (0,1) -- (8,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: too much orange]

which is presumably not what you want.

Why not configure it so that it works in the same way the standard tips do? Then you can say e.g. `blue, fill=red` and get a blue outline with a red core for the tip, regardless of the line colour.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but this works in minimal testing:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name = twocolor,
  parameters = {%
   \the\pgfarrowlength
  },
  setup code = {%
    % The different end values:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    % The hull
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}%
    % Saves: Only the length:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
    \pgfseteorule
    \ifx\pgf@arrows@stroke@color\pgfutil@empty\relax\pgfsetfillcolor{pgfstrokecolor}\else\pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@arrows@stroke@color}\fi
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{.15\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.65\pgfarrowlength}{.4\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.4\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.65\pgfarrowlength}{-.4\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults = {%
   length = 2cm
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [color=red, arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm, blue, fill=orange]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
  \draw [color=red, arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm, orange, fill=magenta]}] (0,1) -- (8,1);
  \draw [color=red, arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm, green, fill=yellow]}] (0,2) -- (8,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: multi-coloured arrow tips]

This works even if only the fill colour is changed:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [color=red, arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm, blue, fill=orange]}] (0,0) -- (8,0);
  \draw [color=red, arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm, blue, fill=magenta]}] (0,1) -- (8,1);
  \draw [color=red, arrows={-twocolor[length=3cm, blue, fill=yellow]}] (0,2) -- (8,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: 3 fill colours]

The complication, of course, is that you need to fill twice, rather than stroking and filling once each. I don't know if arrow tips are safe with two closed paths or if they are really intended to handle only one. But this issue seems to be an inevitable consequence of your tip design.

Comment: Filling twice is fine.  That's what I'm doing with my real arrow.  But I don't want to have one color be stroke and the other be fill; in my real use case it's a fill and an erase.

You've done a nice job of demonstrating the problem.  My proposed solution doesn't have `second color` as one of the parameters that's saved in the setup, so it doesn't create a different setup when it's changed.  I'd like to use `second color` as a saved parameter, and I'm not sure the syntax to use to do it.

Comment: Why make life difficult? You can set up your user interface so it accepts `second color` or whatever you like and then pass it to the arrow tip. Just use a style wrapper. Or forward the value or whatever works. I realise it is filling twice, but the outer fill is functionally stroke-like, so it seems perfectly appropriate to set it that way. I don't know what you mean about the second colour being an erase. If you really want to erase it, why are you drawing/filling it? Just don't draw/fill it. But this isn't at all indicated in your question.

Comment: @CarlSorensen If you are erasing with it (in whatever sense) then the problem I had with your code shouldn't be an issue, since the colour of what is erased is always the same, presumably.

Comment: @CarlSorensen Note that I am filling with the inner colour *first*. That's why I say you can simply not draw/fill it. I have no idea what you are really trying to do, but I can only guess - rather wildly - that you are filling with the background colour the inner part of the tip. But there's no reason to do that. Just fill the outer part of the tip so that the background colour is not obscured in the first place.